# (Solved) How to reach "add to cart" button and price inside Recently Viewed Products Widget in magento 2

Tags: widget, magento2.2.3, recently-viewed

I need to make some custom changes on **add to cart** button and item prices, in Recently Viewed Products widget.
For **add to cart** button, i need some custom php statement,
And for prices i need old price to be displayed on discounted products

I tried to make some edits on:

- `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\widget\viewed\sidebar.phtml`
- `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\ui_component\widget_recently_viewed.xml`
- `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml`

and few more ...

But when i made some changes, nothing seems to appear on page.
Does anyone know where i can edit these elements, so the changes will be applicable for this widget only.
Thanks

[EDIT, WORKING SOLUTION]

I have found the files where i can:

edit button:

- `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\web\template\product\addtocart-button.html`

  extended to ->
- `app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\web\template\product\addtocart-button.html`

edit item elements srtucture:

- `vendor\magento\modulecatalog\view\base\web\template\product\list\listing.html`

  extended to ->
- `app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\web\template\product\list\listing.html`

add some javascript:

- `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\widget\viewed\sidebar.phtml`

  extended to ->
- `app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\widget\viewed\sidebar.phtml`

Comment: You can enable template path hints from admin panel and check which templates are being used, once you know that make sure you make the changes by override in your custom theme and not in the core module.

Answer (score 1):

Check the below 2 files and make changes accordingly to the "Add to cart" button

> ../vendor/magento/module-reports/view/frontend/templates/widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml
>
> ../var/sites/curtmfg/dev13/vendor/magento/module-reports/view/frontend/templates/widget/viewed/content/viewed_list.phtml

Comment: Thanks Shireen,  unfortunately this didn't help. Same when i put it in child theme extension folders